# Is there a way to take input(email-id) from the user and automatically mail the same excel sheet using vba code?

Tags: excel, vba

> In Thisworksheet

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()


     On Error GoTo ErrHandler
        ' SET Outlook APPLICATION OBJECT.
        Dim objOutlook As Object
        Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")



    ' CREATE EMAIL OBJECT.
    Dim objEmail As Object
    Set objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

        With objEmail
            .to = "webadmin@encodedna.com"
            .Subject = "This is a test message from Arun Banik"
            .Body = "Hi there"
            .Display           ' DISPLAY MESSAGE.
        End With

        ' CLEAR.
        Set objEmail = Nothing:    Set objOutlook = Nothing

ErrorHandler:
        '
    End Sub
```

> In Module,
>   So is there way where i can take input from the user and the excel sheet gets sent to respective email id

```
With objEmail


    .To = "arunbanik21@rediffmail.com"
        .CC = "arun@mail.com"
        .BCC = "arun@hotmail.com"
        .Subject = "This is a test message from Arun"
        .Body = "Hi there"
        .Attachments.Add ("e:\report.doc")
        .Send


  End With
```

Comment: Use `Application.InputBox`?

Comment: Hi @BigBen , how to link  'Application.InputBox' with the respective code? any edits suggestion?

Comment: `Dim UserInput as String` `UserInput = Application.InputBox("Your input goes here: ")` then `.To = UserInput`

Comment: @SamuelEverson In which section should I put the above code, In the module or in Thisworkbook section ?

Comment: I've added an answer that answers what you are trying to do, but there can't be much more detail to it as your question isn't really a question!

Comment: @SamuelEverson I have added my version of code and Integrated it with your reply it works now only thing is it gets to the send button and stops i have attached the image where it stops, I want it to send automatically without stopping at send button

Answer (score 0):

This can go in whatever module your code is written in.

Just make sure the [inputbox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.inputbox) code is before you assign your values to your email fields.

Also the msgbox is just to show you what the code does.

```
Sub test()
Dim UserInput As String

UserInput = Application.InputBox("Your input goes here: ")

MsgBox UserInput

End Sub
```

So in your application it could be something like:

```
Dim UserInputToEmail As String

UserInputToEmail = Application.InputBox("Please enter a To address: ")

With oOutlook
    .To = UserInputToEmail 'This will be whatever is put into the InputBox above.
    .CC = "SomeEmail@test.com"
    .Body = "Test Email"
    .Send
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Mail_workbook_Outlook_1()

Dim UserInputToEmail As String

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

 UserInputToEmail = Application.InputBox("Enter your email id")

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .to = UserInputToEmail
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
        .Body = "Hi there"
        .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
        .Send
 Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:15"))
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```